# Making earth pit in swampy area

Tags: grounding, measurement, earth

I recently made an earth pit in a swampy area. I dug the earth up to 5 feet as water was available at 4 feet depth. I poured charcoal and salt in the  ratio of 3:1 . After braising the copper plate and strip together, I left the earth pit to settle. After one month, I found that the earth resistance measurement is not better than 2.2 ohms. I use a four port earth resistance meter ( max reading of 20 ohm)  and cross checked the reading with another meter. What went wrong? Did the excess underground water diluted the earth chemicals? I am expecting a reading better than 1 ohm in this perennial wet land. What is the proper way to make earth pit in a swampy area?

Comment: I hope you mean brazing, not braising :)